# Add a line break between Datatable and button

Tags: css

I don't like the way "CSV" button hugs the bottom line of the Datatable. This CSV button is generated by using the jQuery DataTables [plug-in](https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js)

How can I simply add a line break between the line and CSV button?

[image: screenshot of datatable]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a CSS issue. If you can find the class of the button, then you can apply something like this to it:

```
.button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```